# How much air flow for indoor plants (capsicum chinense)?

Tags: houseplants, vegetables, chili, air-flow

My plants sit on south-facing window sill in the gap between the glass and blinds closed (very little air flow).  The window is on street level of a fairly busy street so the blinds are closed, and as such, there is very little air flow to prevent strangers to see all the craziness inside.  However, that is my only south-facing window and my thumb is not yet green.  These *Capsicum chinense* plants are in a San Francisco window.

**What is the recommendation of this ventilation?  Thanks, you!**

[image: My plants sit on south-facing window sill in the gap between the glass and closed blinds closed (very little air flow)]

Answer (score 1):

Will the blind go down as far as the top of the plants and stop there? If so, then viewers on the outside would see just the blind at the top and the plants on the sill, able to see nothing inside the room. Keep the plants pruned for bushiness to a uniform height and they will have access to good light and air from the room.

Comment: so the blind does go all the way down and there is very little air flow.  is your recommend to not lower the blind all the way?

Answer (score 1):

Although south windows are considered the brightest, it should be noted that north and east windows have some advantages over south windows, especially if your plants are right in the window like that. Here are some advantages:

- They'll get more early morning sun (and that's where plants often make growth spurts). Even for a north window, the sun starts to come up in a northeastern-type direction (so the rising sun will affect plants in a north windowsill, especially those on the west side of the north windowsill). It goes around to the southeast, then to the south and on to the northwest. So, it's not as simple as just from east to west. (At least, that's how the sun moves at my house. I didn't look this up or anything.)
- They should get less sunscald (if that's a problem for you), since less of the sun should be direct.

So, if you can put your plants in such a window in order to give them extra ventillation, I imagine that would be great.

If you'd rather deal with the current window, I might suggest raising the blinds two to a few inches (if that won't compromise privacy), and getting a small fan that blows toward the crack.

Another alternative would be to get something to go in front of the window that rises up to the plant level, and raising the blinds to its level. Then, the view would still be obstructed, and the plant would get more ventilation.

Blinds or no blinds, though, a fan in the room is a pretty good idea, for air circulation (although it doesn't have to be blowing on the plants--they'll dry out faster if that happens). If you have central air, or something, I'm not sure how that affects plants, offhand.